# PHP,MYSQL Getting information from the session

Tags: php, mysql

I created a user page. After logging in on the profile page I wanted to include a username, mail and secret key, but only the username and email are displayed, the secret key is not.

User page code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['zalogowany']))
    {
        header('Location: ../logowanie');
        exit();
    }

    $nick = $_SESSION['username'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

<title>NanoTech</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
<link href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/icon.png"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Profil Gracza</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php include '../../menu.php'; ?>

    <div class="parallax-container">
<div class="parallax"><img src="../../files/tlo.png" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">
</div>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="z-depth-5 card-panel box-kontakt">

    <?php
        echo "<img src='https://mcapi.ca/avatar/$nick/100'>";
    ?>

    <li class="divider"></li>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 black-text ">
    <ul class="tabs black-text">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class='black-text active' href="#test1">Dane</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="black-text" href="#test2">Secret Key</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">
    <?php
    echo "<p><b>Nick</b>: ".$_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<p><b>E-mail</b>: ".$_SESSION['email'];
?>
</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12"><?php echo $_SESSION['secret']; ?></div>

    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </div>


<?php require('../../footer.php')?>

<!--  Scripts-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/materialize.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/init.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Session acquisition code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if ((!isset($_POST['login'])) || (!isset($_POST['haslo'])))
    {
        header('Location: ../logowanie');
        exit();
    }

    require_once "connect.php";

    $polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

    if ($polaczenie->connect_errno !== 0)
    {
        echo "Error: ".$polaczenie->connect_errno;
    }
    else
    {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $haslo = $_POST['haslo'];

        $login = htmlentities($login, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

        if ($rezultat = $polaczenie->query(
        sprintf("SELECT * FROM `authme` WHERE username='%s'",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie,$login))))
        {
            $ilu_userow = $rezultat->num_rows;
            if($ilu_userow>0)
            {
                $wiersz = $rezultat->fetch_assoc();

                if (password_verify($haslo, $wiersz['password']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['zalogowany'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $wiersz['id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $wiersz['username'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $wiersz['email'];
                    $_SESSION['secret'] = $wiersz['secret'];

                    unset($_SESSION['blad']);
                    $rezultat->free_result();
                    header('Location: /');
                }
                else 
                {
                    $_SESSION['blad'] = '<span style="color:red">Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło!</span>';
                    header('Location: /user/logowanie');
                }

            } else {

                $_SESSION['blad'] = '<span style="color:red">Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło!</span>';
                header('Location: /user/logowanie');

            }

        }

        $polaczenie->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: The code should be here. It is very unlikely that this is a mysql issue since the username and email are coming back.

Comment: Added code from linked source.